# How to make radio buttons appear in react.js

Tags: reactjs, input, radio-button

I want to make a form with radio-buttons but the radio-button does not appear only the label appears

```
const PollOption = ({ selected, onChange }) => {
return (
    <div>
    {YES_NO.map((choice, id) => (
        <div key={id}>
        <label>{YES_NO[id].question}</label>
        {choice.choice.map((choices, i) =>(
            <label key={i}>
                <input type="radio"
                    name={YES_NO[id].question}
                    value={choice.choice[i].text}
                    checked={selected === choice.choice[i].text}
                    onChange={onChange} />
                {choice.choice[i].text}
            </label>
            ))}
        </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);
};
```

Comment: Your code is working fine. I created a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c9kcbg). Try to inspect your DOM via browser inspector. Maybe some unwanted style is hiding your radio inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it was a single line that gave me some trouble:

```
checked={selected === choice.choice[i].text}
```

Removing it and my radiobuttons work as they where supposed to.